# How to fix: In a database of a monopoly game, if turn_number=0 (start turn), set bank account amount=3000;

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

trigger that in a database of a monopoly game, if turn_number=0 (start turn), set bank account amount=3000;

```
Create or replace trigger initial_turn
after insert on Recap_turn
for each row
when (new.turn_number=0)
declare 
    i integer;
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    i:=3000;
    update Recap_turn
    set bank_account_amount=i
    where (id_turn=:new.id_turn); commit;
end;
```

after the insert the bank_account_amount remain the same,instead of change to 3000

Comment: it will be helpful to add more details to this so it will be easier for someone to help you

Comment: sorry if there was a lack of other informations, next time i will try to be more complete .>.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER initial_turn
BEFORE INSERT ON Recap_turn
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
    if inserting and :new.turn_number = 0 then
        :new.bank_account_amount := 3000;
    end if;
end;
```